# About Linux script/exit

Tags: linux

The below is not working when i run it as a script and doesn't even do an exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su - test
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/postgres/9.5/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/postgres/9.5/lib

BACKUP_RETENTION=$((7*24*60)) # 1 week
LOG_RETENTION=$((7*24*60)) # 1 week

BACKUP_DIR=/backup/data/pg_backup/
BACKUP_NAME=$BACKUP_DIR"test-db-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M`.zip"
KEY_AUTH=`cat /var/lib/test/.test_file`
LOG_DIR=/backup/log/
LOG_FILE=$LOG_DIR"test-db-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M`.log"

echo "Backup :: Script Start -- $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" >> $LOG_FILE
START_TIME=$(date +%s)

dump_name=$BACKUP_DIR$test_`date +%Y%m%d`.dump
pg_dump -c -p 11381 test -f "$dump_name" &&
zip --encrypt -P ${KEY_AUTH} ${BACKUP_NAME} "$dump_name" &&
rm "$dump_name"

# *** Deleting Backup Based on Retention *** #
find $BACKUP_DIR -name "*.zip" -mmin +${BACKUP_RETENTION} -delete

# *** Deleting Logs Based on Retention *** #
find $LOG_DIR -name "*.zip" -mmin +${LOG_RETENTION} -delete

END_TIME=$(date +%s)
ELAPSED_TIME=$(expr $END_TIME - $START_TIME)

echo "Backup :: Script End -- $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" >> $LOG_FILE
echo "Elapsed Time ::  $(date -d 00:00:$ELAPSED_TIME +%Hh:%Mm:%Ss) "  >> $LOG_FILE

exit 0
```

Comment: Can you remove the script line `sudo su test` and then run the script as root? `sudo /path/myscript.sh` or as user test  `sudo -u test /path/myscript.sh`

Comment: "test" is db/app user. We login as privileged account then sudo to "test" to be able to run the script. We need to keep that within the script..

Comment: You need to not keep the `sudo su - test` within the script. That is what is causing you problems.

Answer (score 4):

The first line in this script launches a new shell under the `test` user ID, and waits for that shell to exit before running the first `export` command to modify the path. The script is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: Hi John, We have to sudo that DB user then set PATHs and run backup due to application requirement and restrictions. I login to server as -- USER 1 then sudo su - (for root) -- then sudo su - test (which is in the script)...What changes i should do to be able to run the script in one go and then exit.

Comment: Do not run `sudo su - test` in that script. Instead, run `sudo -u test <script>`. That will run the script as the 'test' user.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to [John's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387883/203203), you may change your `sudo` line to this:

```
if [ "$(id -un)" != "test" ]; then
    exec sudo -u test "$0" "$@"
    exit
fi
```

What this does is to re-execute the script with user `test` if this is not test that already executes it.